# Как добавить расшифровку цветов, соответствующих меткам классов, в качестве лейблов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Из `dataset iris` надо разнести по 4 графикам 4 признака по столбцам (0-3).
В массиве `y4` лежат метки двух классов 0,1 - они меняют цвет в зависимости от принадлежности к классу.

Как добавить расшифровку цветов соответствующих меткам классов?
В качестве лейблов: 0 - зеленый, 1 - красный (например).

```
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=False)
X4 = data.data
y4 = data.target
names = data.target_names
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))  
    f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize=(15,15), sharex=True, sharey = True)
    norm=plt.Normalize(0,1)
    sc = axes[0][0].scatter(X4[:,0],X4[:,0], c = y4, marker = "x", norm=norm)
    axes[0][0].set_xlabel('0', labelpad = 5)

    axes[0][1].scatter(X4[:,0],X4[:,1], c = y4, marker = 'o', norm=norm)
    axes[0][1].set_xlabel('1', labelpad = 5)

    axes[1][0].scatter(X4[:,2],X4[:,0], c = y4, marker = '*', norm=norm)
    axes[1][0].set_xlabel('2')

    axes[1][1].scatter(X4[:,3],X4[:,3], c = y4, marker = 's', norm=norm )
    axes[1][1].set_xlabel('3')

    cbar_ax = f.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])

    f.colorbar(sc, cax=cbar_ax)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример для одного `subplot`:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize=(15,15), sharex=True, sharey = True)
norm = plt.Normalize(-1.5, 1.5)

scatter3 = axes[1, 0].scatter(X4[:,2],X4[:,0], c=y4, marker='*', norm=norm, cmap="viridis")
legend3 = axes[1, 0].legend(*scatter3.legend_elements(),
                            loc="upper left", title="Classes")
axes[1, 0].add_artist(legend3)
axes[1, 0].set_xlabel('2')
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE:** можно оформить это в виде функции:

```
def my_scatter(ax, loc="upper left", title="Classes", **scatter_kwargs):
    scatter = ax.scatter(**scatter_kwargs)
    legend = ax.legend(*scatter3.legend_elements(), loc=loc, title=title)
    ax.add_artist(legend3)
    ax.set_xlabel('2')

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figsize=(15,15), sharex=True, sharey = True)
norm = plt.Normalize(-1.5, 1.5)

my_scatter(axes[0,0], loc="upper left", title="Classes", X4[:,0],X4[:,0], c=y4, 
           marker='x', norm=norm, cmap="viridis")
my_scatter(axes[0,1], loc="upper left", title="Classes", X4[:,0], X4[:,1], c=y4, 
           marker='o', norm=norm, cmap="viridis")
```

PS код из "UPDATE" не тестировался и может содержать ошибки...

Comment: В качестве лейблов их нет.

Comment: Как справа вообще убрать градацию и оставить только лейблы

Comment: Убрала справа градацию #cbar_ax = f.add_axes([0.85, 0.15, 0.05, 0.7])

Comment: @svil, уточните что вы понимаете под лейблами ?

Comment: Чтобы сбоку было написано 0:"green", 1:"red", 2:"orange" у каждого графика

Comment: Легенда : axes[1][1].legend({0:"green", 1:"red", 2:"orange"}) Но пока только один цвет отображается

Comment: @svil, привел пример решения в ответе...